# Google SignIn: Unable to disconnect iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus-signin

I have implemented google SignIn in my iOS app and can login to google account for the first time. But when I logout and try to log back in, I get Account Permission screen as shown below with last user instead of SignIn screen.

[image]

Below is the code I've used.

```
var signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
signIn.delegate = self
signIn.uiDelegate = self
```

Below is code to sign out & disconnect

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
```

After disconnecting, I again try to SignIn using below code

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

How can I display login screen after Signing out & Disconnecting?

Comment: are you maintaining any logged in and logout state of the app..?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this for a while and I came up with a pretty hacky solution.

It seems the GIDSignIn account listing is using a Safari Web View, so its record of the accounts is using cookies/local storage and is independent of the iOS Keychain (and OAuth tokens).

When a user hits logout on my app I'm opening a SFSafariViewController like so:

```
import SafariServices

class MyViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
...
```

inside your button action (or where you want to log the user out):

```
let logoutUrl = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout")!
let logoutViewController = SFSafariViewController.init(url: logoutUrl)
logoutViewController.delegate = self
self.present(logoutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

where you implement the `didCompleteInitialLoad` delegate method and dismiss your view controller like the following:

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: false) {
        //Switch view controllers
    }
}
```

This seems to be the only way I can figure out.