# Logging out with Google OAuth on iOS

Tags: ios, google-api, google-oauth

I'm using Google's [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) to prompt users to log in and authorize access to their Google account. That much is working, and API calls work as expected.

What's not working is logging out. In the GTMAppAuth code, removing authorization is handled by setting the `GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization` instance to nil, so that the app can't make API calls for the user account.

*Except*, when you reauthorize, Google's authorization flow **does not require a password** to get authorization back. It shows a list of previously used accounts and asks which one you want. If you choose on one, voila, you're in! No need for a password. I have to ask the user's permission, but what if it's a different user? They can get in to the previous user's account, and I need to prevent that. For my app this is not an unusual scenario.

So how do I **really** log out, so that a password would be required to reauthenticate? I'm setting my own `GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization` to nil, and I'm making sure to remove Google's keychain entries, but still no password is required.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between **Authenticaton** and **Authorization**. Your app has no control over Authentication. That's a matter solely for Google and its users.

Comment: Except that in practice it isn't, because there's nothing I can do to let the user de-authenticate themselves with my app. Once they've logged in once, Google lets them back in again without requiring a password. I can't even give users the option to prevent that.

Comment: That behaviour is by design and I don't see it changing. Allowing an app to unilaterally terminate a Google Account session (which is essentially what you're looking for), would be too problematic. It might be worth explaining your use case in a bit more detail, specifically why an iOS device is being used by multiple users, so we can see if there is an alternative approach.

Comment: I don't want to unilaterally terminate anything, I want the user to have the option to do so. This app is used by businesses on devices that may be shared by several people in the same office. I'm trying to allow this sharing without letting people into each other's Gmail accounts. I'm specifically trying to ensure user privacy.

Comment: K, I understand what you're trying to achieve, and I can't see how it's possible. Where you say "I want the user to have the option to do so", that's simply a case of the user navigating to https://accounts.google.com/Logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the only thing that does what I need is to load Google's "logout" page, as [described in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144109/43832). Basically, load `https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout`.

I had thought that the approach would be to revoke the app's OAuth tokens, but that's not actually what I need. I can revoke them, but Google will then issue another one without requiring a password (or it might be the same key-- it doesn't really matter to me if no password is required). I gather that this is based on browser cookies, but since I'm using `SFSafariViewController` on iOS I can't inspect the cookies. Revocation is a waste of time if tokens will be reissued like this.

Loading the logout page seems like kind of a hack but it has the useful effect of clearing out whatever browser state allows resuming access without requiring a password from the user.

On iOS this **could** produce an annoying UI artifact of displaying a web view when the user didn't expect one. But it's easy to prevent that by presenting the `SFSafariViewController` in a way that keeps the web view hidden. I did it like this, but there are other approaches.

```
func logout(presentingViewController:UIViewController?) -> Void {
    guard let presentingViewController = presentingViewController else {
        fatalError("A presenting view controller is required")
    }

    let logoutUrl = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout")!
    let logoutVC = SFSafariViewController(url: logoutUrl)
    logoutVC.delegate = self

    presentingViewController.addChildViewController(logoutVC)
    presentingViewController.view.addSubview(logoutVC.view)
    presentingViewController.view.sendSubview(toBack: logoutVC.view)
    logoutVC.didMove(toParentViewController: presentingViewController)

    // Remove our OAuth token
    self.authorization = nil
}
```

The `delegate` assignment is important. In the delegate, I implemented this to dismiss the `SFSafariViewController` as soon as the logout page loads:

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
    controller.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
    controller.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I understand that you want the user to have to re-enter their password no matter what.

In that case a sub- optimal strategy of revoking the access tokens and disconnecting the app from given account could work. See: https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth/issues/9 which leads you to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#tokenrevoke with their `REST api` because it's not natively supported in the library you are using.

Aside from that, a better strategy could be to consider the usage of the Cocoapods `GoogleSignIn` as they natively support the revoking feature. See: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/disconnect

**Sidenote**: Google's auth flow is designed that way so users can return to the app as quickly as possible, and since most people don't share their phones with others, you wouldn't really have to revoke their certificates.

Hope this helped! Good luck :)

Comment: I think this may be correct but it seems odd. There must be some key, token, credential, whatever that the app presents when it authenticates the user that could be removed locally. I thought that removing Google's keychain entries would remove the local copy of the OAuth key, but it seems like that's not true.

Comment: Also, I've tried both of the methods you mention. They're documented to do what you describe, but in practice neither seems to work. With the demo app for Google Sign-In, the "disconnect" call has exactly the same effect as the "sign out" call.

Comment: @TomHarrington Hmm... could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129888/google-signin-unable-to-disconnect-ios-app and see if that changes anything? Since we are displaying in a web view clearing cookies _may_ work but then again this auth flow was designed this way for a reason.